# CFileDialogImpl: недопустимое имя файла

Tags: windows, atl, c++

Добрый день. У меня есть класс

```
class FileDialog : 
    public CFileDialogImpl<FileDialog>
```

Все работает отлично, выведены два фильтра ".rtf" и "Все файлы". Все ок, но если выбрать фильтр "Все файлы" и ввести имя без расширение вида "Файл" - жалуется, что "Недопустимое имя файла". Очевидно ему не нравится, что отсутствует расширение. А можно как-то отключить эту проверку? Чтобы если "Все файлы" и без расширения, просто выдавал файл без расширения?  Спасибо.

Comment: Проблема решена, стоял SetDefaultExtension(L"*.rtf"); хотя правильно будет просто "rtf". Всем спасибо.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Попробуйте определить фильтр так:

```
char szFilter[] = _T("Rich Text Format|*.rtf|All Files|*.*||");
```